# How do I use a Dictionary with a UITableViewController?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm writing a Xamarin.iOS app and need to bind a dictionary, or ideally a concurrent dictionary to a `UITableViewController`.

Since it's not recommended (or possible) to access the items of the table by indexID, I don't know how to implement the required two overrides:

```
public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
    return peerHistoryMonitor.Count;
}

public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    UITableViewCell cell = new UITableViewCell(CGRect.Empty);

    // Won't compile --- ERROR
    var item = peerHistoryMonitor.Keys[indexPath.Row];

    cell.TextLabel.Text = item.Subject;
    return cell;
}
```

I could make a copy of the dictionary's keys and store that in an array... and update it upon a refresh.

- Is there a better way? Or did I just figure out the best practice of achieving this?
- Should I consider something other than a Dictionary?

Comment: I would probably copy Keys into a list or array

Comment: A `OrderedDictionary` might be an option (but I do not know your design of the Dictionary usage). Or using the `ElementAt` on the Keys property (but that is a real code-smell). Personally for Datasource-based Cocca/iOS controls I would avoid a standard Dictionary as a ***vector is required*** for indexing and keeping two separate data structures in sync just for the UI presentation in a  UITableView has a real smell about it, but again that is a personal opinion.

Comment: My current plan is to move to a MVVM architecture, make the dictionary part of the view, and the ViewModel a static "snapshot" of the Model.  Tips and advice on how to approach this (and refreshing) is ideal. I'll likely use Prism for DI if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not ordered and because of that can't be accessed with a index. You should use any `IOrderedCollection`. Probably a List is the best practice.

Why do you have a Dictionary? Is it necessary in your implementation?
A TableView isn't a visual representation of a Dictionary.